Is there a way to update or edit the traits on the metadata on opensea?
I'm kind of new to NFT and Is there a way to edit or add traits in NFT that are already minted. on ERC-1155
Example:
Trait:
Color - Eye Purple
To
Trait:
Eye Color - Purple
Shirt Color - White
I tried searching for it but there is no topic I found that is very helpful. I even try to find "Edit NFT" button but there is none.
